# Unbounded function on compact interval?

Tags: functions, continuity, compactness

So what are some unbounded function on compact interval, if there is any?

Also, is the function $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=x$ continuous?

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is most certainly a continuous function.

Comment: Any example (uncluding mookid's below) is necessarily discontinuous: The image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact (in this case it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and so it is bounded).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For instance, $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=1/x$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$ is defined on a compact domain $[-1,1]$ but it is not bounded.

Recall the Weierstrass theorem:

"Every continuous function on a compact domain has at least one maximum and one minimum"

So negating the above statement we obtain that:

"No maximum or minimum and the function has compact support then it must be discontinuous"

In other words, if you look for an unbounded function (in particular, no maximum or minimum) defined on a compact domain then you must look for a discontinuous function.

Comment: $f$ is not defined on all of $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: picky mathematicians :P Now it´s fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

consider for example
$$f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R\\
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac 1x &\text{if} & \frac 1x\in\Bbb N, x\neq 0 \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

which is unbounded on $[0,1]$.